Python UDP server start failed with error code WinError 10045 in Windows
I am trying to build Python UDP server using the following code.

import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
    bind_port = 30335
    
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP, Server setting
    server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
    
    print("[*] Listening on %s:%d " % (bind_ip, bind_port))
    
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print('Connected by ', addr)
    
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print("Client recv data : %s " % (data))
    
            client.send("ACK!")

And I got an error below
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\jimmy\desktop\github\worldlongcompany\python\main.py:20
    client, addr = server.accept()

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\socket.py:294 in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()

OSError: [WinError 10045] The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Is there anything wrong with my code? I am new to Python and please let me know how can I fix it.
My Python version:
> ! python --version
Python 3.11.8


could you have forgotten to listen on the socket documetation

@KenzoStaelens: There is no listen for UDP sockets the same there is no accept.

oops missed that somehow, my bad

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP, Server setting
...
    client, addr = server.accept()

accept is an operation for TCP sockets. You are creating a UDP socket though (SOCK_DGRAM). With UDP there is no connection establishment preceding the data exchange, i.e. no connect and accept. Instead data are directly exchanged on the socket using send and recv.

I am new to Python ...

This is unrelated to Python. It is the same behavior with sockets in other programming languages.

How can I use UDP socket correctly?

@JimmyHu: As I said: use send and recv directly on the socket, no accept etc. I'm pretty sure that there are zillions of examples online for this and that these are easy to find.
